# Wordpress $cf7->posted_data Missing - no data available to push to sessions

Tags: wordpress, forms

Suddenly (I did nothing) my Contact 7 forms (wordpress) stopped working properly.

My functions.php was working with the submitted data - affecting all my forms.
This is affecting 2 sites I manage and seemed to happen to both at same time.

```
    add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'my_conversion');

    function my_conversion($cf7)
    {
    $firstname = $cf7->posted_data["FirstName"];  
    }
```

The problem is that $cf7->posted_data["FirstName"] is blank for some reason - no value.  Yet my form has a field named FirstName.

Any ideas?

Suddenly my $cf7-posted_data is empty...even when I try and push the data to a session (I have sessions working on my wordpress sites) the value is empty...

Comment: Did you updated something on those WordPress sites? Which version of WordPress are you using?

Comment: WordPress 3.9.1 - no updates.

Answer (score 6):

If you have CF7 v3.9 the posted_data property is depreciated see below...

```
/* WPCF7_ContactForm object no longer has a posted_data property. */
$posted_data = $contact_form->posted_data; // Wrong.

/* Use WPCF7_Submission object's get_posted_data() method to get it. */
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

if ( $submission ) {
    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
}
```

Comment: This is correct, for further information view the changelog or [The Docs](http://contactform7.com/2014/07/02/contact-form-7-39-beta/)